# (Rational) polynomial in two variables of degree 3 with no roots in projective closure

Tags: polynomials

First of all I think the following statement is true: Given a polynomial $f\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ of degree $3$, there is always at least one solution $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ for $f(a,b)=0$, right? What if I replace all $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb Q$? Does the statement still remain true including the case at infinity? (Edit: The answer is no, see comments.)

Is there any criterion for $K$ such that there exists a polynomial in $K[x,y]$ of degree $3$ that does not have any roots in $K^2$ nor at infinity, i. e. $\mathbb P^2(K)$? Why are the cases $K=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$ different from $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: For the case of coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, we could let $x=y$ and thus get a cubic polynomial in one variable.  It is well-known that every real cubic polynomial has a least one root (by a continuity argument).  This argument  breaks down if we restrict ourselves to *rational roots*, but you haven't quite said that when the polynomial has rational coefficients, you are only interested in excluding rational roots.

Comment: Right, that was my thought, too (for $\mathbb R$). Right, by _roots_ I mean respectively to the given field $K$, in this case $(a,b) \in \mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: So for $\mathbb{Q}$ we should be satisfied by exhibiting a cubic polynomial *in one variable* with no rational roots?

Comment: My bad, didn't read though carefully. (but yes, a polynomial in one variable is still a polynomial in 2 variables as well...)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I actually want to consider the projective closure, so $x^3-2$ does have the root $[0:1:0]$ at infinity.

Comment: Selmer's cubic $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3$ has only $(0,0,0)$ for a rational solution.

Comment: Thank you, of course! But what if $K=\mathbb F_2$ or an arbitrary field? What conditions must the field fulfill to have roots for any polynomial over that field?

Comment: @Thrash:  Are you now asking about when a field is algebraically closed?

Comment: No, $\mathbb R$ for example is not algebraically closed, but every real polynomial in two variables of degree $3$ has at least one root. Sorry, I meant _for any polynomial of two variables of degree $3$_.

Comment: "For the case of coefficients in $\mathbb R$, we could let $x=y$ and thus get a cubic polynomial in one variable."
By the way, this method doesn't work for $x^3-y^3+x^2+1$.